# Regaining focus in iFrame with jQuery context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've created a fiddle to reproduce the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/rvwp47Lz/23/

```
callback: function (key, option) {
    console.log("You clicked the test button", this);
  // Need the iframe contents to regain focus so the mouse events get caught
  setTimeout(function () {
      $iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
  }, 100);
}
```

Basically, what I want to happen is the mouse move events to be caught after closing the context menu.

I can call focus on the iFrame's body or document but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

After you right click one of the items within the iframe and select an item, the mousemove event on the iframes body is no longer called (you can also notice that the hover CSS effect on the items are no longer working).

Ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to get this work in Chrome. Apparently this isn't an issue in FF.

Comment: It also appears that it's not really a focus issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging and playing around with jQuery.contextMenu's code it seems the issue actually comes from the itemClick function. I added comments to the code and will add an issue to their github for a possible fix (unless there's some reason they're disabling default here)

```
        // contextMenu item click
        itemClick: function (e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data(),
                opt = data.contextMenu,
                root = data.contextMenuRoot,
                key = data.contextMenuKey,
                callback;

            // abort if the key is unknown or disabled or is a menu
            if (!opt.items[key] || $this.is('.' + root.classNames.disabled + ', .context-menu-submenu, .context-menu-separator, .' + root.classNames.notSelectable)) {
                return;
            }

            // This line is causing the issue since it's preventing the default actions which puts
            // mouse events back into place. Chrome must disable mouse move events when the contextmenu event
            // gets triggered to improve performance.
            //e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```